# Azure BotFramework V4 possible to get facebook webhook page feed event?

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-apps, azure-bot-service

I have a bot that subscribes to a facebook page feed and listens to user's comments; however, the azure bot v4 framework webhook doesn't seem to provide a response for this in the bot code.

Can I do this in a single FB app, or do I have to split it into 2 Facebook apps: one for the bot framework and the other for listening to the webhook?

Comment: You can do both under one app id.

Comment: how can I get the webhook page feed information in bot framework? I had enabled  bot framework page feed but `adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {}` doesn't have that info about fb comments

Comment: Because the webhook for Azure bot is setting like: `https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/{mybotname}`, how possible for me to retrieve the webhook info sent by FB without the access to facebook.botframework.com?

Comment: Webhooks for Messenger Platform and Graph API are two different things. If you like to handle the latter with a different app - subscribe a different app.